# grdb not working variables

Tags: debugging, assembly, variables

i know this is kinda retarded but I just can't figure it out. I'm debugging this:

```
xor eax,eax

mov ah,[var1]
mov al,[var2]

call addition

stop: jmp stop

var1: db 5
var2: db 6

addition:
add ah,al
ret
```

the numbers that I find on addresses var1 and var2 are 0x0E and 0x07. I know it's not segmented, but that ain't reason for it to do such escapades, because the addition call works just fine. Could you please explain to me where is my mistake?

---

I see the problem, dunno how to fix it yet though. The thing is, for some reason the instruction pointer starts at 0x100 and all the segment registers at 0x1628. To address the instruction the used combination is i guess [cs:ip] (one of the segment registers and the instruction pointer for sure). The offset to var1 is 0x10 (probably because from the begining of the code it's the 0x10th byte in order), i tried to examine the memory and what i got was:

```
1628:100 8 bytes
1628:108 8 bytes
1628:110 <- wtf? (assume another 8 bytes)
1628:118 ...
```

whatever tricks are there in the memory [cs:var1] points somewhere else than in my code, which is probably where the label .data would usually address ds.... probably.. i don't know what is supposed to be at 1628:10

---

ok, i found out what caused the assness and wasted me whole fuckin day. the behaviour described above is just correct, the code is fully functional. what i didn't know is that grdb debugger for some reason sets the begining address to 0x100... the sollution is to insert the directive ORG 0x100 on the first line and that's the whole thing. the code was working because instruction pointer has the right address to first instruction and goes one by one, but your assembler doesn't know what effective address will be your program stored at so it pretty much remains relative to first line of the code which means all the variables (if not using label for data section) will remain pointing as if it started at 0x0. which of course wouldn't work with DOS. and grdb apparently emulates some DOS features... sry for the language, thx everyone for effort, hope this will spare someone's time if having the same problem...

heheh.. at least now i know the reason why to use .data section :))))

Comment: i didn't understood what "escapade" took place? you didn't describe the problem: what do you see what do you expect.

Comment: I expect values 5 and 6 at [var1] and [var2]

Comment: @Andrey - that is incorrect. If you want the value of an address you must dereference it, just like dereferencing a pointer. `[var1]` is the correct way of dereferencing an address in x86.

Comment: I want to learn assembler now, even a stupid idiot knows it! (no offense)

Comment: but that would store the address.. not the actual value.

Comment: right right, sorry, i was wrong. try add ".data" as Yuval A suggests.

Comment: umm.. i know it's a bit stuborn but that's what I don't want to do, because that would make the code look differently than i wrote it. I want to see how does it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is x86 assembly, `var1` and `var2` must reside in the `.data` section.

---

**Explanation:** I'm not going to explain exactly how the executable file is structured (not to mention this is platform-specific), but here's a general idea as to why what you're doing is not working.

Assembly code must be divided into data sections due to the fact that each data section corresponds directly (or almost directly) to a specific part of the binary/executable file. All global variables must be defined in the `.data` sections since they have a corresponding location in the binary file which is where all global data resides.

Defining a global variable (or a globally accessed part of the memory) inside the code section will lead to undefined behavior. Some x86 assemblers might even throw an error on this.

Comment: It is x86 assembly. I know it should be in the data segment but what's the deal, it shouldn't matter if the data are not mixed with instructions. Why does the label point somewhere else?

Comment: It **does** matter, the placement of the assembly instructions is critical to where they end up on the executable file.

Comment: I thought ELF is not really necessary if you just take your chances reading the code without symbols... I'm using windows btw...

Comment: well, without labeling the stuff, it should end up in the order as it is written. which shouldn't be a problem..   ?